# How to read/calculate the stiffness setting of a joint on a NAO robot

Tags: c++, nao-robot

I have a C++ program that communicates with the Naoqi DCM, sending commands and reading status information, but I cannot find a way to read a joint's stiffness setting directly.

Naoqi has the following `ALMemory` keys for a particular joint, *left shoulder pitch* in the example below.

```
Device/SubDeviceList/LShoulderPitch/Position/Actuator/Value
Device/SubDeviceList/LShoulderPitch/Position/Sensor/Value
Device/SubDeviceList/LShoulderPitch/ElectricCurrent/Sensor/Value
Device/SubDeviceList/LShoulderPitch/Temperature/Sensor/Value
Device/SubDeviceList/LShoulderPitch/Hardness/Actuator/Value
Device/SubDeviceList/LShoulderPitch/Temperature/Sensor/Status
```

Whilst I am able to write to the above actuators and read from the sensors, I need to determine the joint's stiffness setting, however Hardness is a write only actuator and cannot be read.

I've looked at the values that the `ElectricCurrent` sensor returns and have determined that it alone does not give the desired result.  Even with stiffness set to maximum, if the arm is at its destination pose and there is no displacing torque force, the `ElectricCurrent` reports zero current for the joint.  Thus you cannot assume that stiffness is off when there is no current.

Anyone know how to determine the stiffness setting of a joint without using `motionProxy.getSummary()`?

Comment: When you start, set a default value and then keep track of the values you set?

Comment: I'm already doing that.  However, if the process is reset, or the walk module, which writes directly to the DCM while making adjustments, then the state becomes unclear. I need to be able to determine what the current state of the robot is simply by reading some values.

Comment: I'm not agreeing with your statement: "Device/SubDeviceList/LShoulderPitch/Hardness/Actuator/Value" is write only. I'm quite sure you can read it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ALMotionProxy.getStiffnesses(jointNames)](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-8/naoqi/motion/control-stiffness-api.html#ALMotionProxy::getStiffnesses__AL::ALValueCR).